# To attach a VF page as a File in the record

Tags: visualforce, attachment, files, contentversion, contentdocument

I have attached a VF page in Notes/Attachments. But now i wanted it to get attached in Files.
The below code is working fine if i attach it in Notes/Attachments.

```
Blob pdfBlob;
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.QuoteGeneration;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',quoteId[0]);
        pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
        List<Quote__c> quoList = [select Id, name, (SELECT Id FROM Attachments) from Quote__c where id=:quoteId[0]];
        integer n = quoList.isEmpty() ? 0 : quoList[0].Attachments.size();
        n=n+1;
        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = quoteId[0], name= quoList[0].name+'-V'+n+'.pdf', body = pdfBlob);
        insert a;
```

How do i do the same in files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ContentVersion to upload the file, then use a ContentDocumentLink to link the file to the record.

```
Integer pdfCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Attachments WHERE ParentId = :quoteId[0]] + 1;
Quote__c pdfParent = [SELECT Name FROM Quote__c WHERE Id = :quoteId[0]];

ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
  Title='Hello', 
  PathOnClient=pdfParent.Name+'-V'+pdfCount+'.pdf', 
  VersionData=pdfBlob
);
insert cv;

cv = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv.Id];
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
  ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId,
  LinkedEntityId = pdfParent.Id,
  ShareType = 'I', // Inferred Share
  Visibility = 'SharedUsers'
);
insert cdl;
```